# Create expression-blend-like buttons style

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I want to create a button style like expression blend buttons in this way:

- when the mouse is not over them, their icons are black-white and
  semi-transparent.
- When the mouse is over them, they get color and become clear without transparency.

Is it possible to create such a style for XAML icons without coding in expression blend ?

Note that I dont want to use 2 icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a Paths instead of an image you can use the Visual State to switch from showing the paths with a border and transparant fills to the original a very easily.

You can use [InkScape](http://inkscape.org/) to convert your own images to paths(xaml), search prepared images online on sites like [Xamalot](http://xamalot.com/) or use a tool like [Syncfusion Metro Studio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) to create the xaml you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Sorskoot. Can I Create a style to switch between this two state for **all Path objects** inside a content control (if possible without coding in blend), and apply it to all buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like this could be a good place to start.

You have 2 images(these are from an online source, bit you can replace with a resource .png) the "iconfocus" will be visible when the mouse is over the button, and the "iconNofocus" will be visible when not.

This is a very rough example:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="PART_border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="Highlight" Opacity="0">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0.1" StartPoint="0.5,0.8">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#90009FFF" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}"  Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}">
                                        <Image x:Name="iconFocus" Margin="2" Opacity="0" Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Folder-icon.png"/>
                                        <Image x:Name="iconNofocus" Margin="2" Opacity="0.5" Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Folder-Generic-Green-icon.png"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Highlight" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="iconFocus" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="iconNofocus" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Normal:
[image]

Mouse Over:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Is there a way to use only one image (colored one)?

Comment: sure, but if you don't want to simply use a black and white image you will have to create an image converter class to convert the image to black and white or find some kind of other way to transform the image to black and white. IMO it would be easier to just have 2 images.

Comment: Can it be done without coding in expression blend for XAML icons?

Comment: I don't know I have never used expression blend, and I have never heard of a xaml icon

Comment: Thanks to help me clarifying. I updated my question to reflect my true intention.

Comment: XAML icons are icons that graphic is expressed in the path and geometry object format. examples can be found in visual stdio image gallery.

Comment: Ahh.. I always call geometry geometry not icons.